# Java - Using two values from a database in a combobox

Tags: java, swing, sqlite

I'm developing a simple Java program to retrieve info from a database and show it to the user, I want to take the info of certain tables and add it to a combobox (Or whatever works) but still be able to get the id back when I select an option.

For example let's say I have a table like this

```
people table

id  name
---------
1   Roger
2   Mike
3   Bob
```

What I want to do is retrieve all the names to show them in a combobox, and if I choose let's say 'Mike' from the options list, I want the program to be able to give me back the id for Mike so I can use it in another select. Is it possible? If not, is there a better way to do what I want to do without having to use the name in a select? I already have a method to get the info I need and put it into a hashmap, I don't know if I can use it somehow.

Also, another related question, what is a better practice for this kind of programs? To retrieve info from a database and have it available all the time without having to read the database again? Or to read the database only for the info I need at the moment and do it every time?

Edit:
I'm using Swing GUI

Comment: What GUI library? Swing?

Comment: You can use a ComboViewer (JFace) and set the input as an array of People objects (So that you have id associated with a name). Then a selection listener to get the id of selected person

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Which GUI library? Swing? If so then:

- Create a class that holds your name String (or Strings) and has a field for the id, perhaps an int, but probably better also a String (that holds numeric characters). Say we call this class NameAndId, and make sure that it has adequate getter methods, equals, haschCode, and whatnot.
- One option is to create a JTable whose rows are objects of the class above, and whose model, here one that extends from AbstractTableModel, holds an `ArrayList<NameAndId>` of objects NameAndId type. Then one column of the JTable would display data from the id field and one (or more) for the name and other fields.
- Another option is to create a `JComboBox<NameAndId>`, give it a `DefaultComboBoxModel<NameAndId>`, and then fill this model with NameAndId instances. If you only want to display the name, then you have one of two options: either give NameAndId a `public String toString()` method that displays what you want the JComboBox to show. This is the easiest solution but one that is not recommended by experts as it forces you to change a model class for it to work in a view or display class, something that should be avoided.
- Another option is to do the above, but give your JComboBox a custom renderer, one that displays just the name information from the NameAndId objects that it holds. This is the most robust solution of the two. For more on this, please be sure to check out the [renderer section of the JComboBox tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#renderer).

Note that since the models that you've used, whether it's a TableModel or a ComboBoxModel, hold objects of NameAndId, then whatever item is selected will hold all the information that you need, even if it doesn't display all that information in the GUI.

Comment: delca7, `...This is the most robust solution of the two.` - I disagree with this statement since it breaks the default functionality of the JComboBox. That is you can no longer select items in the combo box by using the starting characters of each item in the combo box. See [Combo Box With Custom Renderer](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/11/17/combo-box-with-custom-renderer/) for more information on this topic.